# Convert a formula (cm,kg) in (mm,grams)

Tags: language-agnostic, formula, units-of-measurement

I have a question about this formula from a book:

> EFW (cm,kg)= 10^(-1,7492+(0,166*BPD)+(0,046*AC)-(2,646*AC*BPD/1000))

The result is in kg, while BPD and AC are given in cm.

I would like to use this formula to get the result in grams and my value for BPD and AC is given in mm. So how can I get it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1000*10^(-1,7492+(0,166*BPDm/10)+(0,046*ACm/10)-(2,646*ACm/10*BPDm/10/1000)) 
or
10^(3-1,7492+(0,0166*BPDm)+(0,0046*ACm)-(2,646*ACm*BPDm/100000))
or
10^(1,2508+(0,0166*BPDm)+(0,0046*ACm)-(2,646*ACm*BPDm/100000))
```

result*1000 to convert a value from kg to g,
if BPDm and ACm given in mm, BPDm=10*BPD and ACm=10*AC, so BPDm/10=BPD and ACm/10=AC